# Fasting on an airplane

Tags: fast-days, travel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast days and time zones](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/fast-days-and-time-zones)

If I am flying from Israel to NY during Tisha B'Av do I have to fast for 32 hours, or can I end the fast when it ends in the place where I was?

Comment: duplicate (merger suggested): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12965/759