# Determining times of Halachic import on a long flight

Tags: halacha, zemanim, travel, how-to, vehicles-transportation

If I'm taking a long flight on an airplane on a day when permitted activities change at a certain point, e.g. with the start or end of a fast day, or with the start of the [*chametz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chametz) prohibition kicking in before Passover, how can I determine the right time to observe the change in status?

Similarly, how can I determine the right time windows in which to pray the morning prayer, afternoon prayer, etc.?

Comment: debbie, Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I'm going to take the liberty of drastically generalizing your question, since we've had [this sort](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36181/tanis-esther-start-on-the-elal-flight) of very particular question before, and it would be good to have a canonical reference for a real answer. See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/fast-days-and-time-zones .

Answer (score 3):

[The Chai Air Tables](http://www.chaitables.com/chai_air_eng.php?look=20150730) are a fantastic tool I've used many times and have seen others use many times.

One simply inputs one's flight route (i.e. source, destination, departure date and time) and the website provides a table (including additional columns for each 15-minute interval of delay) of different Halakhically-relevant times.

Here is an example of what their tables provide:

[image: Chai Tables Example]

Comment: I realize this answer may be insufficient as it's simply a link. If necessary, I can remove it.

Comment: (Re your comment.) No, the question was "How can I find out when to..." and this is an answer ("by using the Chai tables"), not a link to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check myzmanim.com, which will give you in-flight zmanim charts. Every airline and every flight is different. Essentially, you need to calculate the flight path of the airplane (which can change right before take-off). Then you need to find the zmanim of your current location (that is, the sea-level equivalent of your location.) Those are the zmanim that apply to you in flight.

Comment: Does it take into account elevation?