# Airplane Zmanim

Tags: halacha, zemanim, travel

If one is on an airplane, what zmanim does he follow? I see two feasible options: those of where he actually is, and those of the ground below where he is.

Zmanim are affected by altitude as well as latitude/longitude according to some opinions. The higher up you are, the later the sun sets. One flying at 30,000 feet gains a few extra minutes over those on the ground beneath him. So which zmanim does he follow?

(I'm assuming that a third option, the zmanim of his [takeoff place](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat), wouldn't work as a possibility, as there is actually sunrise/sunset where he is, unlike an astronaut.)

Comment: Are you asking according to the opinion that we generally take altitude into account, according to the view that we don't, or both?

Comment: Dont have a source, but most rabonim say to daven based on the ground where you are. That is based on many years of flying transatlantic.

Comment: Two sites that offer davening times for air travelers: https://www.myzmanim.com/airdemo.aspx
http://www.chaitables.com/ChaiAirTimesProProgram.php

Comment: Rav Moshe has a teshuva about this have to remember where though

Comment: @mevaqesh I didn't realize there was such an opinion that we don't care about altitude. So then according to the one that we do.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55644/determining-times-of-halachic-import-on-a-long-flight

Comment: Adding to @YehudaW's comment, I think that MyZmanim has a rather detailed article that discusses altitude issues as well as how times are affected when flying. It discusses the rules and "theory" behind these calculations. If ElAl passenger behavior is an indication of correct halacha, it seems that davening occurs based on where the plane is located and not the time of the city you departed from / going to or your residence. (I can just imagine the confusion that would arise if it were the last choice.)